# How to query the aligned and unaligned time series separately in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I realized that in Apache IoTDB, time series can set to be aligned or unaligned, and two types of time series can simultaneously be stored.

I wonder if I set these two types of time series at the same time, and I want to check the aligned and unaligned time series separately, how should I write my query statement in Apache IoTDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query using `show devices` first, and there will be a column to show whether this time series is an aligned time series or not. Then you can query `show timeseries root.xx.xxx` separately for aligned or unaligned time series in Apache IoTDB.